# Is there a way to get the received and transmitted wifi waveform from an iPhone?

Tags: wifi, waveform

I want to get the wifi waveform for a project involving signal processing, I was wondering if one of you heard of a way to get such an access ?

Comment: You mean like get a machine that reads and shows the microwave signals going through the air?

Comment: Ideally, I mean embedded on the device, for prototyping. I want to get a reading on the signals that a phone would have given all the interference he could get and emit.

Comment: Possibly related but I just realized that if you Alt (Option) click the WiFi icon on a Mac, you can click Open Wireless Diagnostics. From there you can click Window in the menu bar and some of those windows like Performance may have relevant charts. Not sure if that's what you needed though.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked it, unfortunately, those data are not sensitive enough for signal processing. There is a "detector" windows that generates *.wcap files within the tool, but those are packets related data.